# How to deploy a particular visual webpart on a sharepoint site

Tags: sharepoint, deployment

I have created a sharepoint empty application in visual studio 2012, after that i have added 2 different visual web part and  created one list through code.
when i click the deploy button, all the above 3 are deployed to the site.
i dont want this, i want only one particular visual webpart to be deployed to the site.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Remove the visual webpart from the project and then deploy the solution.